# how to connect mysql in flash builder 4.5 with java

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash-builder, blazeds

while i am connecting the dateservice via menu  Data> connect to BlazeDS  the error showing that RDS server message : connection refused : connect

Comment: I had added tags to get more solution

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Blazeds tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html) and also see the java with Mysql connection